# DegradedArray event on /dev/md2

Tags: raid, hard-drive

I am getting the following error on my Proxmox server. It has happened multiple times over the last few days now. How am I able to test if the RAID hard drive is faulty?

```
    This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm
running on myserver

A DegradedArray event had been detected on md device /dev/md2.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [raid1] 
md4 : active raid1 sda4[0] sdb4[1]
      1931980736 blocks [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 2/15 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid1 sda2[0]
      20478912 blocks [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```

parted -l

```
Model: ATA HGST HUS724020AL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      20.5kB  1049kB  1029kB                  primary  bios_grub
 2      2097kB  21.0GB  21.0GB  ext3            primary  raid
 3      21.0GB  22.0GB  1073MB  linux-swap(v1)  primary  raid
 4      22.0GB  2000GB  1978GB                  logical  raid


Model: ATA HGST HUS724020AL (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      20.5kB  1049kB  1029kB                  primary  bios_grub
 2      2097kB  21.0GB  21.0GB                  primary  raid
 3      21.0GB  22.0GB  1073MB  linux-swap(v1)  primary
 4      22.0GB  2000GB  1978GB                  logical  raid


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/pve-data: 1974GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  1974GB  1974GB  ext3


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md2: 21.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  21.0GB  21.0GB  ext3


Error: /dev/md4: unrecognised disk label
Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md4: 1978GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

Comment: Look at your logs, you will see some errors before pushing out the defect hard drive.

Comment: I gave an elobrate answer [here](http://serverfault.com/q/723763/31475)

Answer (score 1):

You an use [smartctl](http://linux.die.net/man/8/smartctl) to examine the SMART data on the drive and run tests.

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdb
```

is a good starting point. You can also run tests

```
smartctl -t short /dev/sdb 
smartctl -t long /dev/sdb
```

etc.

You may also get some informatio from the system logs.

Comment: Where would those logs be after running the tests?